# How to validate invoices state draft odoo

Tags: odoo, import-from-csv, odoo-accounting

My problem is to import my invoices, I go to Accounting -> Invoice Client -> Import. From there, I put my Excel file EBP containing all my invoices. I select the different fields to import (customer, date, product, price, quantity, taxes ...) but I do not find the payment fields (that is the date of payment, the amount paid. ..). Basically, I can import my invoices with the customer's name, invoice date, different billing lines, VAT ... but I can not import to indicate whether the invoice was paid, What date, what? The amount was paid ... I can not find the corresponding fields when importing!

I did not arrive, so I tried to import all my invoices without paying them and then import the payments separately into the menu Accounting -> Payments Client -> Import. The problem is that I can not link the payment to the invoice at the time of import.

I hope to have been clear. More generally: how to import an invoice already paid? I have more than 4500 invoices to import, so I really need something automatic. I also tried to go through the menu "bank statements", I can settle several bills at once, the problem is that I can not specify the correct payment dates (at least not case by case I can not Only specify a date for all invoices, which I do not agree with)

Comment: I am afraid you have to validate and make the payments by hand. There are some modules to import invoices, but I think they import the invoices in draft state. Maybe you can try automating using some script. A wizard appears when you create a payment, so attempt to emulate its behaviour. `shell` module could be useful to make some action on console

Comment: Have you tried OCA's reconciliation widget ? It gives a way to match payment and invoice easily. 
https://odoo-community.org/shop/account-reconciliation-widget-8893?search=reconciliation_widget#attr=14598